# A specific class of $(0,1)$-matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $T_n$ be the class of $(0,1)$-matrices of order n with no row sum equal to a column sum. Is there any name or research about this kind of matrix?

For any $A\in T_n$, let $S_A$ be the sum of all the entries of $A$. I found when $n$ is even, for most $A\in T_n$,$S_A$ is even, but I do not know how to describe it exactly. So I ask for some help!

Comment: What does the second paragraph mean: you have a proof that, for $n$ even, most matrices in $T_n$ have even number of $1$'s, or you mean that you computed up to some $n$, and observed this to be this case. In the latter case, how large was your $n$? In the former case, is your question "is this already known"?

Comment: I computed up to $n=4,6$, and observed this to be this case, so I just want to ask if there exist any research about this.

Comment: Interesting question. I currently doubt that this pattern will persist for larger $n$, but have no proof.